# parse.com | how to show results on UITextView ?

Tags: objective-c, uitextview, parse-platform

this is my test query

```
PFQuery *lookingForSomething = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"AprilMessage"];
[lookingForSomething whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[lookingForSomething findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    // nothing here

 for (PFObject *objectFound in objects) {

       NSLog(@" this is my objectFound", objectFound);
```

so far so good, the results of my NSLog(objectFound) are :

```
{
message = hello world ! ;
reciever = "<PFUser:WNOmhmrO3L>";
user = "<PFUser:WNOmhmrO3L>";
```

what i'm trying to do is getting the message string " hello world ! " and show it on the screen , 
here what I did but it's not working for some reason

```
 // same code from before just adding the last lines down there

PFQuery *lookingForSomething = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"AprilMessage"];
[lookingForSomething whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[lookingForSomething findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

// nothing here

   for (PFObject *objectFound in objects) {

   NSLog(@" this is my objectFound", objectFound);

   // adding this new line

 objectFound[@"message"] = _textChat.text;  <-- textChat is a UITextView !!!
```

any idea where did I go wrong  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last line is backwards. It should be,

```
_textChat.text = objectFound[@"message"];
```

This should work assuming that both _textChat and objectFound[@"message"] are not nil.